# Displaying Images with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, image

I am doing a project in Visual Studio where users can first see all the latest images that is uploaded by different users. And then when a user clicks on one of the images displayed, the image will be displayed in another page with details about the image such as the name and date that the image was uploaded.I am not sure on how to go about doing and need help. I am doing this on Visual Studios 2010 using C#. These are the things I need to know:

1. How to display the latest images that were uploaded
2. How to display the image that the user clicked on an another page with the image details.

I already have a database where the image and the image info will be saved. I am not sure on how to do the rest. I would appreciate code samples and sample projects.

Comment: The latest image you could get from your database, just save the upload date and select the newest. Use the onclick event to figure out which image was clicked and get all the necessary information from your database. But first of all, I would desperately recommend to read the MSDN tutorials and learn the fundamental stuff. Here more informations: [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/asp.net/ff380144.aspx)  [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd566231(v=vs.100)). Greetz

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview) and you can start by following the [MVC Movie App tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3). Then you will have to redo it replacing movies by images...